# Google Spreadsheets: How to html publish pages based on current day

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

intro : I'm using a published google spreadsheet with a day schedule, each day is on a page. 
Currently I'm just embedding the sheet with html/css in a webpage, this webpage is being reloaded every half hour so the sheet is pulled again and newly added data is shown.

Problem 1: Every time the page reloads the embedded sheet shows the first page. And it because very annoying for the staff that looks at that sheet.

Question :Isn't it possible to link the day in the page to the current day of the month?

Motivation question : I've been looking and trying with timers and manually adding all the sheet pages links into the code, but thats a lot of waste time every month, when my boss duplicates the sheet and alters everything for that current month. 
So every month the pages in the sheets get new links.

I'm searching for somebody that has tackled this issue in de past and succeeded or didn't succeed and can give me alternative ways of solving this (like awesome table?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have editing (and file-restructuring-decision-making) privileges for the Sheets file itself, perhaps consider making a new first sheet, named something like "Today", which uses a formula to automatically always just show today's schedule, which in turn still just lives where it always has. The published page will accordingly then just show today's schedule, since it's the first sheet.

Say your Sheets file's "tabs" for each day are just named the number of the day, so: "23", or "24", or "25"…  A formula in the "Today" sheet might pull in the day's schedule with something like this:
`=INDIRECT(DAY(TODAY())&"!A1:Z")`

In English, from the inside out, that formula means: take [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)'s date and time, extract just the [DAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040) number of it, put that day as text next to the hard-coded text `!A1:Z`, and now that we're done assembling it, use that text instead as an [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) reference to the actual cells we want shown here.

[Demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z3gIqvo6cXuPty3WVzZ7B3_Poi_cDLpfUE-qk12uZ3g/edit?usp=sharing) here. Note that the demo only works on the 23rd - 25th of a given month because those are the only day schedule sheets I created. You can find the above formula in sheet `Today`, cell `A2`. If your file's other Sheets are named something different, edit your question and we can assist with a formula to suit.

An important note if you choose an approach like this. The result of the formula is to *display* the other day's schedule in however-many cells it takes, starting where the formula is entered. The data then shown cannot be edited in place, and if data is entered say… next to the schedule, it will not be reflected back on the actual sheet for that day.